Early to mid 2000 reality dating show where a woman dates 3 men
It's basically about a middle aged woman dating 3 middle aged men. They show up and do stuff for her. The woman at the end picks 1 guy she likes. She has I believe 3 adult sons.  Here's what I remember:

One of the men does something for the White House and says he knows G.W. Bush. The second man is an African American with a goatee and I think he was an artist. The 3rd man I can't remember what he does.
The 3 adult children have a football match with the 3 men.

Family Guy did a joke about it once. That's about all I can remember.
Anyone know what show is this?

Is this the plot of the whole show or of one specific episode from it?

I can't remember exactly. Could have been an episode.  The 3 men show and do stuff for her. The woman at the end picks up 1 guy she likes. Also I remember the middle aged African American man having a goatee.

There were several different dating shows where the girl picks from 3 men. Without more detail, I'm not sure you can get a definitive answer.

Well it's a middle aged woman with 3 adult sons. The contestant are 3 middle aged men. One of the men is african american. Also family guy did a joke about it once. I just can't find the clip. Not sure how much more details I can give.

This is an episode of "Meet My Folks" from 2003 "The Haegeles (Meet My Kids)", the 6th episode in Season 2.

Single mom Barbara Haegele's three grown sons choose a date to escort her on a trip to Hawaii in this expanded edition. Included: a football game between sons and suitors; secret tasks; and a lie-detector test.

This extensive recap of the episode also specifies that one of the 3 (middle aged) suitors is an artist and another is a politician who shows them pictures from his White House visit.
Specifying that they're 3 sons in the comments was a big help.
